# mysql_num_rows for prepared statements? php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
$q = $dbc -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? && logcount = ''");
$q -> bind_param('s', ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
$r = $q -> execute();
    if ($r) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
            echo 'Account Active';
        }
        else {
            header('location: create');
        }
    }}
```

I know this code doesn't work, I have searched for an answer to mysql_num_rows for prepared statements and know where has an answer that I can find!

Thanks.

Comment: what's with the email = ? bit?

Comment: @boisvert: It's called a prepared statement.  The [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) line will replace the `?` with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: @Rocket, basic: oops... read question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`num_rows` is a member of the prepared statement class.  It's set after calling `execute`.

```
$q->num_rows;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: Is there a page on the net where I can find all of these functions for the prepared statements? And thanks for your answer bud!

Comment: I think you need to call $statement->store_result() before getting num_rows

Comment: @xzdead: I'm not sure